# Trying to select a MenuItem, and have it show in the Select, not showing, Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Trying to have a dropdown menu with the first MenuItem as the default choice in the box until you click it, then the dropdown menu comes down and gives you options to select, such as 1, 2, 3, and when you click on it, the choice shows up and the dropdown menu goes away

```
class App extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rigName: '',
      desc: '',
      choice: '',
      customAttribute: ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // const response = await 
    // this.props.onSubmit(response.data);
    console.log(this.state)
    // this.setState({rigName: ''})
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({choice: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    return ( <FormControl variant="outlined" size="small" style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>
                      <InputLabel id="demo-customized-select-label">{this.state.choice}</InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
                        id="demo-customized-select"
                        onChange={() => this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.choice}
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="">
                          <em>None</em>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>ID</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>PSA</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>ExternalID</MenuItem>
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Right now, the dropdown menu works, but the choice doesn't show up after I click on it, any ideas why? or what Im missing?

Update
I have changed inside Select to

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

and am now getting this error
`A component is changing a controlled SelectInput to be uncontrolled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled SelectInput element for the lifetime of the component.`

Comment: You need to specify the `value` prop on all your menu items.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be putting the choice in the label. The label should stay consistent. https://codesandbox.io/s/width-on-outlined-input-znlot